# Nginx responds with 200 even when HTTP HOST header is different from SNI

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, sni

I have just started learning about nginx and SSL and  haven beentrying around different configurations.
I have two server blocks like the following:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.a.com;
    ssl_certificate a.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key a.key;
    ....
}
server{
    listen 443 ssl ;
    server_name www.b.com;
    ssl_certificate b.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key b.key;
    ....
}
```

After connecting to nginx through openssl s_client using www.a.com as my SNI, I sent a GET request using Host: www.b.com and it still works. Is this expected? Can someone help me understand the behavior of nginx?

Comment: I wonder if Nginx just routes the request to the server most appropriate to handle the request.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. What happened when you reported it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A HTTP connection is just a TCP connection at the end of the day. So the above is actually fine for HTTP connections (i.e. if you connect to [www.a.com](http://www.a.com), you are actually connecting to an IP address and not [www.a.com](http://www.a.com), so it's actually fine and expected for that connection to be able to address requests for [www.b.com](http://www.b.com)).

For HTTPS, like you are saying you are using, it's a little less clear cut...

For HTTP/1.1, there is nothing in [HTTP Over TLS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) nor the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), to state how this should be handled, as SNI is a non-mandatory extension to HTTP added after (in fact, as an aside this was one way of getting around clients - like IE8 on XP - if the same cert is used for both virtual hosts, then the appropriate connection could be used after the TLS session was negotiated based on that cert as provided by the default host). However the [SNI RFC clearly states that the server MUST check this is the same](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-11.1), so when a server name is given and is different to the host, what you are observing is incorrect (thanks to Michael Hampton for pointing this out as I missed this originally).

HTTP/2 is more clear in this and in fact does allow connection reuse in certain conditions and [has this to say](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#reuse):

> A connection can be reused as long as the origin server is
> authoritative (Section 10.1). For TCP connections without TLS, this
> depends on the host having resolved to the same IP address.
>
> For https resources, connection reuse additionally depends on having a
> certificate that is valid for the host in the URI. The certificate
> presented by the server MUST satisfy any checks that the client would
> perform when forming a new TLS connection for the host in the URI.
>
> An origin server might offer a certificate with multiple
> subjectAltName attributes or names with wildcards, one of which is
> valid for the authority in the URI. For example, a certificate with a
> subjectAltName of *.example.com might permit the use of the same
> connection for requests to URIs starting with https://a.example.com/
> and https://b.example.com/.

So if a.crt also includes include [www.b.com](http://www.b.com) in the Subject Alternative Name field then above is actually fine under HTTP/2, though not under HTTP/1.1.

However, just to be sure, I have repeated your observations when a.crt definitely does NOT cover [www.b.com](http://www.b.com) and and that does indeed sound like a bug and also potentially a security risk, as a request for one virtual host could be read by another virtual host (despite not having access to the key that message was decrypted with) if someone was able to inject an invalid host header (which thankfully browsers do not make easy to do - so admittedly I cannot demonstrate this). This could leak cookies or other information to the secondary server.

I have raised this to the nginx security team who say that it is not a security flaw with nginx, and that it is up to the client to validate certificates, and then not to send malformed requests for hosts that they should be accessing over that connection. I strongly disagree with this,and say that the whole point of HTTPS is to only allow valid endpoints to unencrypt messages! So I think the check should be on both the client **and** the server side and in fact [this exact scenario was discussed by the TLS working group at that time that SNI was specific, which is why above wording was added to the RFC](http://ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg03811.html). Additionally, the nginx security team say that in this scenario nginx should be set up with a joint certificate for both hosts (which makes no sense to me as severely limits the usefulness of virtual hosting in nginx!), but if a nginx server operator really wants to restrict this, then they can do by checking the `$ssl_server_name` variable (which to me means it's a relatively easy check that nginx could do by default!). Anyway it's their software and so their entitled to their opinion but I disagree.

It’s also been pointed out that this technique is sometimes used for avoiding censorship in a process known as [Domain Fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_fronting). Which is fair enough but which I think should be explicitly enabled rather than be allowed by default.

Incidentally Apache does not do the same and (correctly IMHO) returns a "400 Bad Request" prior to 2.4.17 and the new "421 (Misdirected Request)" after 2.4.17 - [which was a new HTTP status code created especially for this scenario](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-9.1.1).

Comment: [RFC 6066 section 11.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6066#section-11.1) specifies that the Host: header MUST match the server name in the TLS ClientHello, for exactly this reason. Of course with HTTP/2, you might be able to reuse a connection in the way indicated.

Comment: Good spot. I have edited the answer to include this information - thanks.

Comment: I have also flagged this issue to the Nginx security mailing group and flagged the question for moderator intervention to decide if to hide it until they have a chance to respond.

Comment: @BarryPollard: Can you send us a link to the report?

Comment: @Sven it is just an email at this point (as per http://nginx.org/en/security_advisories.html) though I asked them to let me know if they wanted a ticket raised in their bug tracker: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/

Comment: @Sven I have added nginx's response. I'd be interested to hear other's opinion on this.

Comment: I think this behaviour is a bad idea. I don't see any pros in working this way, but I am sure there are ways this behaviour can be abused. What if one vhost had client TLS certificate authentication enabled, and another vhost doesn't have it enabled. Could one access the vhost with authentication required via the TLS connection to the other vhost and without needing to actually have a client certificate?

Comment: Actually to be fair to Nginx they do check this with client certificates for reasons you give and use 421 there (https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,267026). I left that out of my answer for simplicity. They say it’s complicated (particularly for HTTP/2) and not necessary to do it for server certs.